# Displaying the variable names according to the sequence appeared in the regression models using `texreg`

Tags: r, regression, texreg

Using `texreg`, I am trying to display the variable names according to the sequence appeared in the regression models. For instance:

I create an interaction term of `Sepal.Width`and `Petal.Length`.

```
iris$Interaction = iris$Sepal.Width * iris$Petal.Length
```

I run two regressions, one without and one with the interaction term:

```
OLS1 = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris)
OLS2 = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Interaction + Petal.Width, data = iris)
screenreg(list(OLS1, OLS2))
```

When exporting the regression table, `texreg` would throw the `interaction` term at the very bottom. However, it would be much easier for reader to check the results if the `Interaction` term appears right below the `Sepal.Width`and `Petal.Length` in `OLS2` instead of the bottom (considering that I have a very big regression table).

This is the output using `texreg`:

[image]

Is there any way to configure the `texreg` package so that the newly added variable would appear according to the order in the model instead of appearing at the bottom?

Comment: Your answer was indeed very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use option `reorder.coef` of `texreg::screenreg()`.

```
texreg::screenreg(list(OLS1, OLS2), reorder.coef = c(1:3, 5, 4))
```

Or, more general:

```
rrdrd.coef <- c(seq_along(names(coef(OLS2)))[-which(names(coef(OLS2)) == "Interaction")], 
  which(names(coef(OLS2)) == "Interaction"))

texreg::screenreg(list(OLS1, OLS2), reorder.coef = rrdrd.coef)
```

***Yielding***

```
====================================
              Model 1     Model 2   
------------------------------------
(Intercept)     1.86 ***    1.30 *  
               (0.25)      (0.51)   
Sepal.Width     0.65 ***    0.82 ***
               (0.07)      (0.15)   
Petal.Length    0.71 ***    0.87 ***
               (0.06)      (0.14)   
Interaction                -0.05    
                           (0.04)   
Petal.Width    -0.56 ***   -0.53 ***
               (0.13)      (0.13)   
------------------------------------
R^2             0.86        0.86    
Adj. R^2        0.86        0.86    
Num. obs.     150         150       
RMSE            0.31        0.31    
====================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```